# How to remove a specific event listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have these two event listeners:

```js
client.on("foo" () => {console.log("bar")});
client.on("foo" () => {console.log("foobar")});
```

I can set them as variables:

```js
var foobar = client.on("foo" () => {console.log("bar")});
var foofoobar = client.on("foo" () => {console.log("foobar")});
```

The `.on` function returns the `eventEmitter`, or in this case: `client`.

Can I remove the `foofoobar` listener, but keep the `foobar` listener? `removeListener()` sounds like something that should work, but it does not. It will removes all events named `foo`.

I could do something hackish like this:

```js
client.on("foo" () => {console.log("bar")});
client.on("foo" () => {console.log("foobar")});
client.removeListener("foo");
client.on("foo" () => {console.log("bar")});
```

However, that is not DRY*. That is WET*, and what I consider as bad practice.

- DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself.
- WET = Write Everything Twice.

I'm writing this in Typescript, but I assume that wouldn't matter in this case, as this is about Node.JS rather than the TS Engine...

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the function separately instead of inline, you can remove it the same way you add it:

```js
const handler = () => console.log("bar");

client.on(“foo”, handler);
client.off(“foo”, handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the listener by providing it as the second argument to `removeListener`. Importantly, you need a reference to the same function to do so.

```js
const foobarFunction = () => {console.log("foobar")};

client.on("foo" () => {console.log("bar")});
client.on("foo", foobarFunction);
client.removeListener("foo", foobarFunction);
```